# PETSc - MatMultScale? Matrix X vector X scalar

Tags: petsc

I'm using **PETSc** and I wanted to do something like,

[image: Equation]

I know I can do:

```
Mat A
Vec x,y

MatMult(A,x,y)
VecScale(y,0.5)
```

I was just curious if there is a function that would do all of these in one shot. It seems like it would save a loop.

```
MatMultScale(A,x,0.5,y)
```

Does such a function exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function (or anything close) does not seems to be in the list of [functions operating on Mat](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Mat/). So a brief answer to your question would be...no.

If you often use $y=\frac12 Ax$, a solution would be to scale the matrix once for all, using `MatScale(A,0.5);`.

Would such a function be useful ? One way to check this is to use the `-log_summary` option of petsc, to get some profiling information. If your matrix is dense, you will see that the time spent in `MatMult()` is much larger than the time spent in `VecScale()`. This question is meaningful only if a sparce matrix is handled, with a few non-null terms per line.

Here is a code to test it, using 2xIdentity as the matrix :

```
static char help[] = "Tests solving linear system on 0 by 0 matrix.\n\n";

#include <petscksp.h>

#undef __FUNCT__
#define __FUNCT__ "main"
int main(int argc,char **args)
{
    Vec            x, y;      
    Mat            A;           
    PetscReal      alpha=0.5;  
    PetscErrorCode ierr;
    PetscInt n=42;

    PetscInitialize(&argc,&args,(char*)0,help);
    ierr = PetscOptionsGetInt(NULL,"-n",&n,NULL);CHKERRQ(ierr);

    /* Create the vector*/
    ierr = VecCreate(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,&x);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = VecSetSizes(x,PETSC_DECIDE,n);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = VecSetFromOptions(x);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = VecDuplicate(x,&y);CHKERRQ(ierr);

    /*
     Create matrix.  When using MatCreate(), the matrix format can
     be specified at runtime.

     Performance tuning note:  For problems of substantial size,
     preallocation of matrix memory is crucial for attaining good
     performance. See the matrix chapter of the users manual for details.
     */
    ierr = MatCreate(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,&A);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = MatSetSizes(A,PETSC_DECIDE,PETSC_DECIDE,n,n);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = MatSetFromOptions(A);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = MatSetUp(A);CHKERRQ(ierr);

    /*
This matrix is diagonal, two times identity
should have preallocated, shame
     */
    PetscInt i,col;
    PetscScalar value=2.0;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        col=i;
        ierr   = MatSetValues(A,1,&i,1,&col,&value,INSERT_VALUES);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    }

    ierr = MatAssemblyBegin(A,MAT_FINAL_ASSEMBLY);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = MatAssemblyEnd(A,MAT_FINAL_ASSEMBLY);CHKERRQ(ierr);

    /*
     let's do this 42 times for nothing :
     */
    for(i=0;i<42;i++){
        ierr = MatMult(A,x,y);CHKERRQ(ierr);
        ierr = VecScale(y,alpha);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    }

    ierr = VecDestroy(&x);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = VecDestroy(&y);CHKERRQ(ierr); 
    ierr = MatDestroy(&A);CHKERRQ(ierr);

    ierr = PetscFinalize();
    return 0;
}
```

The makefile :

```
include ${PETSC_DIR}/conf/variables
include ${PETSC_DIR}/conf/rules
include ${PETSC_DIR}/conf/test

CLINKER=g++

all : ex1

ex1 : main.o chkopts
    ${CLINKER} -w -o main main.o ${PETSC_LIB}
    ${RM} main.o

run :
    mpirun -np 2 main -n 10000000 -log_summary -help -mat_type mpiaij
```

And here the resulting two lines of `-log_summary` that could answer your question :

```
Event                Count      Time (sec)     Flops                             --- Global ---  --- Stage ---   Total
                   Max Ratio  Max     Ratio   Max  Ratio  Mess   Avg len Reduct  %T %F %M %L %R  %T %F %M %L %R Mflop/s
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- Event Stage 0: Main Stage

VecScale              42 1.0 1.0709e+00 1.0 2.10e+08 1.0 0.0e+00 0.0e+00 0.0e+00  4 50  0  0  0   4 50  0  0  0   392
MatMult               42 1.0 5.7360e+00 1.1 2.10e+08 1.0 0.0e+00 0.0e+00 0.0e+00 20 50  0  0  0  20 50  0  0  0    73
```

So the 42 `VecScale()` operations took 1 second while the  42 `MatMult()` operations took 5.7 seconds. Suppressing the `VecScale()` operation would speed up the code by 20%, in the best case. The overhead due to the for loop is even lower than that. I guess that's the reason why this function does not exist.

I apologize for the poor performance of my computer (392Mflops for VecScale()...). I am curious to know what happens on yours !

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tested your code and it works fine (except that a few lines were missing). I guess maybe it is not worth the hassle to implement if the effects are small. Interestingly enough I have almost exactly the same result for MatMult (5.77s 73Mflop/s) and worse for VecScale (2.68s 156Mflop/s). I guess my computer is even worse